# What is the purpose of the PID file for NTP?

Tags: ntp

One of the standard configuration settings of the ntp daemon is to set the name and path to a file where the PID of the ntp daemon currently running is stored.

In the past, [this file has been a source of severe system vulnerabilities](https://www.checkpoint.com/defense/advisories/public/2015/cpai-2015-1342.html).

What is the purpose of this entry of the configuration file and why does the PID need to be stored in a file?

Comment: [This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296170/what-is-a-pid-file-and-what-does-it-contain) might help. Would vote to close, but that's on a sister network.

Comment: Older init systems didn't have a method of tracking processes, so hacks like pid files had to work around that lack of functionality.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588294/5132 .

Comment: @jordanm Ok, so does that mean I can avoid having a pid file for ntp?